# Problem URL JQuery Mobile button Home

Tags: php, url, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two pages, the first is called `index.html` and has a login button that changes the page  to `conexion.html` with this code :

```
$('#page').live('pagecreate',function(event){
    $("#login").bind("click", function(event) {
        $.mobile.changePage( "conexion.html",{ transition: "flip"});
    });
});
```

the URL changes to

> http://localhost/mobile/olapromo/#/mobile/olapromo/conexion.html

in "connexion.html" I call back "index.html" with this code :

```
<a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right jqm-    home">Home</a>
```

when I click on the home button the URL change to

> http://localhost/mobile/olapromo/#/mobile/olapromo/index.html

and I can't access to `conexion.html` any more

Comment: If you have multiple question, please post two separate questions

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you can't access conexion.html anymore?  Do you mean when you click the login button nothing happens?

If that's the case;

Where is the pagecreate handler you are using defined at?  Is it in the page or like in a document.ready handler?

Consider changing the .bind to [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and see if that works.

Comment: i put this but it doesn't work                         $('a').live("click", function(event) {
        $.mobile.changePage( "index.php",{ transition: "flip"});
    });

Comment: Can you make an example on jsfiddle.net?  You don't seem capable of giving more information about what "can't access" means.  Is there a javascript error?  Does it say "Error Loading Page"?  Does nothing happen? Do pink elephants take a dump on your screen...? I got nothing.